# Frame thickness with titlesec

Tags: titlesec, rules, framed

How to change the thickness of the frame using titlesec?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\normalfont}{\filleft\Huge\bfseries\ Chapter 7\ }
{30pt}{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}\section{this section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add something like `\setlength{\fboxrule}{5pt}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\normalfont\setlength{\fboxrule}{5pt}}{\filleft\Huge\bfseries\ Chapter 7\ }
{30pt}{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}\section{this section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was very helpful!